# node.js splice too slow for more than 70000 items

Tags: arrays, node.js, v8

I am newbie in node.js.

i tried to insert 70000 items into array , and then delete all of them:

```js
var Stopwatch = require("node-stopwatch").Stopwatch;
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.create();


var a = []
stopwatch.start();

for (var i = 1 ; i < 70000 ; i++){
    a.push((parseInt(Math.random() * 10000)) + "test");
}

for (var i = 1 ; i < 70000 ; i++){
    a.splice(0,1);
}

stopwatch.stop();

console.log("End: " + stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds + " : " + a.length);
```

It works fine and output is:

```
PS C:\Users\Documents\VSCode> node test.js
End: 51 : 0
```

But when i increase number of items to 72000 , it takes too much time to end:

```js
var Stopwatch = require("node-stopwatch").Stopwatch;
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.create();


var a = []
stopwatch.start();

for (var i = 1 ; i < 72000 ; i++){
    a.push((parseInt(Math.random() * 10000)) + "test");
}

for (var i = 1 ; i < 72000 ; i++){
    a.splice(0,1);
}

stopwatch.stop();

console.log("End: " + stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds + " : " + a.length);
```

And the output is:

```
End: 9554 : 0
```

Why it occurs? only 2000 items added more , but it takes too much time.

Node.js version is: v6.11.3

Comment: Do you know if the explosion of time takes place in the array population or destruction, or both?

Comment: @apsillers in destruction ' a.splice(0,1); '

Comment: Just been investigating / playing around with this - for me the upper limit is 71109 - after this, it's really slow. 71110 for example, takes 12476ms! 71109 is 64ms

Comment: Looking at the [v8 source code for arrays](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/a787c3f9e12d8f392f56d7116dbf1fac09b12123/src/js/array.js), I see that v8 has two different `splice` operations internally. One is for full, normal arrays; the other is for sparse arrays (`['foo',,,,,'bar',,,,]`) and objects. Possibly, v8 might be processing the larger array using its slower fallback `splice` for some reason.

Comment: Win7x32, Node 5.11.1: slowdown on 172000.

Comment: @AikonMogwai 172000 or 72000??

Comment: Definitely 172k.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

V8 developer here. Removing (or inserting) array elements at the start (at `array[0]`) is generally very expensive, because all the remaining elements have to be moved. Essentially, what the engine has to do under the hood for every one of these `.splice(0, 1)` operations is:

```
for (var j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j++) {
  a[j] = a[j+1];
}
a.length = a.length - 1`
```

In some cases, V8 can employ a trick under the hood where the beginning of the object is moved instead -- in the fast cases, you can see the amazing speedup that this trick provides. However, for technical reasons, this trick cannot be applied for arrays beyond a certain size. The resulting "slowdown" is actually the "true" speed of this very expensive operation.

If you want to delete array elements fast, delete them from the end (at `array[array.length - 1]`), e.g. using `Array.pop()`. If you want to delete all elements in one go, just set `array.length = 0`. If you need fast FIFO/"queue" semantics, consider taking inspiration from ring buffers: have a "cursor" for the next element to be read/returned, and only shrink the array when there's a big chunk of elements to be freed up. Roughly:

```
function Queue() {
  this.enqueue = function(x) {
    this.array_.push(x);
  }
  this.dequeue = function() {
    var x = this.array_[this.cursor_++];
    // Free up space if half the array is unused.
    if (this.cursor_ > this.array_.length / 2) {
      this.array_.splice(0, this.cursor_);
      this.cursor_ = 0;
    }
    return x;
  }
  this.array_ = [];
  this.cursor_ = 0;
}
```

---

Side note: It doesn't matter here, but for the record, to push 70,000 elements into your array, your loop should start at 0: `for (var i = 0; i < 70000; i++) {...}`. As written, you're only pushing 69,999 elements.

Side note 2: Rounding a double to an integer via "parseInt" is pretty slow, because it first formats the double as a string, then reads that string back as an integer. A faster way would be `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000))`. (For the purposes of this test, you could also simply push `i`.)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I did something like

```
if (i % 1000 === 0) {
    console.log(i + " " + stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds + " : " + a.length);
}
```

inside the 2nd loop. (This is painfull to compute, but it will help diagnose the problem)

I was not suffer the performance loss. But, I think, that I found why "only" 2000 more things to do is that hard for node. First - my difference:
[loop max num, unit, 3 benchmarks results]

70k: [ms] ~26k, ~25.7k, ~26k
72k: [ms] ~25.6k, 27k, 25.7k

Okay, as I saw the logging, I seen that, the last 10k records are computed like instant. I think that `splice` removes 1 item from the front, and then - one by one it shifts array 1 index "to the start", let's change our test to 10 arrays every with 10k records to see if it will be much better. I will do this in the most lazy way:

```
var Stopwatch = require("node-stopwatch").Stopwatch;
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.create();

var a1 = [], a2 = [], a3 = [], a4 = [], a5 = [];
var a6 = [], a7 = [], a8 = [], a9 = [], a10 = [];

stopwatch.start();

function fill (arr) {
    for (var i = 1 ; i < 10000 ; i++){
        arr.push((parseInt(Math.random() * 10000)) + "test");
    }
}

fill(a1); fill(a2); fill(a3); fill(a4); fill(a5);
fill(a6); fill(a7); fill(a8); fill(a9); fill(a10);

let removeCount = 0;
function unfill(arr) {
    for (var i = 1 ; i < 10000 ; i++){
        arr.splice(0,1);
        removeCount++;

        if (i % 1000 === 0) {
            console.log(i + " " + stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds + " : " + arr.length);
        }
    }
}

unfill(a1); unfill(a2); unfill(a3); unfill(a4); unfill(a5);
unfill(a6); unfill(a7); unfill(a8); unfill(a9); unfill(a10);

stopwatch.stop();

console.log("End: " + stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds + " removeCount " + removeCount);
```

And, yes... I did not answered why exacly your pc have such performance loss between 70k and 72k records - I belive it is something machine dependant... probably lack of RAM, but don't get it wrong - I don't know.

I solved how to improve that. The 100k(-10) on 10 arrays execution time was around 73-74 ms. I think, you can write it into 2d array and modify logic to compute length and rest of things as you want.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: "probably lack of RAM" no it's not lack of RAM , i have 6GB of ram and about 70% of it is free.